# OpenCV C++, Define a background model

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, background-subtraction

I am busy converting and interpreting software used in previous years of my final year project.
I would just like to check if it is possible to define a background model in a header file, as i am currently getting an error.

```
class CWaterFill
{
public:
    void Initialise();
    Mat ContourFilter(Mat Img, int minSize);
    Mat superminImg;

protected:  
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 m_bg_model;//Define the background model.

};
```

[image]

It is then used in the .cpp file in the following function:

```
void CWaterFill::GMM2(Mat InputImg, int nFrame, double learnRate)
{
    m_bg_model(InputImg, m_fgmask, learnRate);//m_fgmask outlook is
}
```

Comment: use pointer to abstract type or concrete implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pointer to an abstract `BackgroundSubtractor` object:

```
...
protected:  
    cv::Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> m_bg_model;//Define the background model.
```

And then create the concrete type, e.g.:

```
m_bg_model = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(20, 16, true);
```

Comment: void CWaterFill::GMM2(Mat InputImg, int nFrame, double learnRate)
{
 m_bg_model(InputImg, m_fgmask, learnRate);//m_fgmask is output
}  // If this is the only place that it is used, where would I add the concrete type definition?

Comment: @JamesMallett in the constructor of `CWaterFill`